# How can you compare values from two columns in two separate tables?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I want to compare the last value in one column in a table with every value in the column of the other table. After many tries can't seem to be able to achieve it.

```
Something like that: In this case I want to compare Value 3 with every value in column 4.

Table_1:
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
| value1  | value4  |
| value2  | value5  |
| value3  | value6  |
+---------+---------+


Table_2
+---------+---------+
| column3 | column4 |
+---------+---------+
| value7  | value10 |
| value8  | value11 |
| value9  | value12 |
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: How would we identify that `value3` is the *last* value in the (unfortunately named) column `column1` in table `Table_1`? How would we determine which row is considered to be *last*? And it terms of comparing that value to the values in a column of another table... what would be the expected resultset? Return rows from `Table_2` that have a matching value? Return a count of the number of rows that didn't match? Absent an actual specification, it's not possible to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subselect  using max

```
select * from Table_2
where  Table_2.column4 = (select max(column1) from table_1 )
```

or using order by

```
select * from Table_2
where  Table_2.column4 = (select column1 from table_1 order by column1 DESC limit 1)
```

or using max(id)

```
select * from Table_2
where  Table_2.column4 = (select column1 from table_1 having id = max(id))
```

Comment: value3 is not the max it's random. What I want is to compare everything in column 4 to lets say the last value in column1.

Comment: I have update the answer ... the problem is related with what do you mean for last ...

Comment: I mean the value that is in the bottom of column1. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: @ThP: Which row is returned at "the bottom" is going to depend on the predicates in the query, and the `ORDER BY` clause. Without an `ORDER BY` clause, the database can return rows in any order so *any* row could be at "the bottom", and the result would conform to the specification.

Comment: @scaisEdge Oh. Thank you very much for the information!